# Dompdf size reduction working well in Localhost but not in live

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf, dompdf, html-to-pdf

Size reduction code working well in localhost but when i test it live my pdf page showing blank with this code   `($dompdf->getOptions()->setIsFontSubsettingEnabled(true);)`

and when i remove above line ..pdf is working fine but size is 18MB.i want to reduce my pdf size to 50KB with this same font family.

```
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8"/>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <div style="width:800px; height:970px; padding:20px; border: 10px solid #787878">
        <style>
          body {
            body {font-family: "NotoSansCJKtc-Regular"}
          }
        </style>

        <div style="width:750px; height:915px; padding:20px;  border: 5px solid  #787878">
          //pdf content is here
        </div>
      </div>
    </html>'; 

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->getOptions()->setIsFontSubsettingEnabled(true);

/* Render the HTML as PDF */
$dompdf->render();
header('Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="' .  $no . '.pdf"', true);

/* Output the generated PDF to Browser */
$dompdf->stream();
```

Comment: Is that really the HTML you're using? For best results you should make sure the structure [validates](https://validator.w3.org).

Comment: Do you get a blank PDF or no PDF and just a blank HTML page?

Comment: @BrianS got blank HTML

Comment: More than likely PHP is running into a fatal exception. If you have error logging enabled take a look in the PHP logs.